# Is rolling a 60 face die (D60) the same as rolling 10 6 faced ones (D6)?

Tags: probability, dice

I understand that if you roll $10$ $6$-faced dice (D6) the different outcomes should be $60,466,176$ right?  (meaning $1/60,466,176$ probability)

but if you are playing a board-game, you don't care about that right? what matters is the sum of the numbers in the end, so it should anyway be $1/60$ instead of whatever right? because its a sum not $10$ individual rolls.

so a $60$ face die (D60) should be the same as rolling all the dice right? if not can someone please explain? I've been looking all over the net for a compelling answer but there is none. I've seen a D60 can be used as $2$ D6 but also there is no explanation for this.

if not, what would be the number of faces needed for an equivalent single die that can replace $10$ D6. I know so far the D120 is the last possible die that can be made, but it doesn't matter, I just want to know too...

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to mention in some tabletop games Dice can have $0$, so you'd treat all $6$ sided dice as going from $0$ to $5$, making minimum value of $0$ possible in all $10$ rolls. But still that changes the maximum in the same way minimum used to be, now the max you get in 6 sided dice is $50$, while on the 60 sided die it would be $59$ if we apply a $-1$ to all results... it gets messy, and this detail doesn't really change much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have heard that you can't use a 60 faced die to replace 10 6 faced dice. I just want clarification on why not, when the result that matters is the sum. In board-gaming a 60 faced die is known as a D60 and a 6 faced one is known as a D6. I added the terms because I hope that can make it easier for other board-game players to find my question easily.

Comment: If you roll 10 D6 then the minimum sum is 10, but if you roll 1 D60 you get can all numbers from 1-10? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: If you label the D6 dice, there is a way to simulate one roll of a D60 die.  Not very convenient but it is possible.

Comment: Analogize to two dice.  Besides the fact that with two dice, you can't roll a $1$, is the distribution of the numbers $2,3,\cdots, 12$ the same when rolling two dice and adding the numbers as it is when rolling a single 12-faced die?  For example, when rolling 2 dice, the chance that they total $(7)$ is (1/6).

Comment: Re previous comment, continuing the analogy of 2 dice versus a 12-sided die : if you don't care that the 2 dice distribution will be heavily distributed around *the middle*, and only care about the average size of the roll: the average of the roll of two dice is $(2 \times 3.5) = 7$, while the average of a 12-sided die is *close* : $(1/2) \times [12 + 1] = 6.5.$

Comment: Your chances of getting the maximum 60 on a 1d60 roll is $1/60$. To get a sum of sixty on 10d6 you need all ten dice to give you six. That happens only once out of $6^{10}=60466176$ rolls. In other words, once out of 60 million. On a 10d6 you have to extraordinarily lucky (or unlucky) to get anything outside the range from $20$ to $50$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the probability distribution of the sum of the faces of rolling $10$ $6$-sided dice is different than that of rolling a single $60$-sided die.

For obvious reasons, this is because you can roll any number between $1$ and $9$ with a $60$-sided die, but cannot attain such a sum with $10$ $6$-sided dice.

The probability distribution of a single $6$-sided die can be modeled with the generating function
$$\frac{1}{6}(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)$$
Where the coefficient of $x^k$ is the probability of rolling a $k$. Moreover, the probability distribution of the sum of rolling $10$ $6$-sided dice can be modeled as
$$\frac{1}{6^{10}}(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^{10}$$
Where the coefficient of $x^k$ is the probability of rolling a sum of $k$. It can be clearly seen that this expansion is completely different than the generating function that models the probability distribution of rolling a $60$-sided die i.e.
$$\frac{1}{60}(x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^{59}+x^{60})$$

However, there are some interesting ideas that you can get from using these generating functions. For example, we have that
$$\frac{1}{6}(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}x(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}x(1+x^3)(1+x+x^2)$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}x(1+x)(1-x+x^2)(1+x+x^2)$$
We can take two dice, and say that their generating function for their probability distribution is
$$=\frac{1}{6^2}x^2(1+x)^2(1-x+x^2)^2(1+x+x^2)^2$$
$$=\frac{1}{6^2}[(1+x)(1+x+x^2)x^2][(1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1-x+x^2)^2]$$
$$=\frac{1}{6^2}[x^2+2x^3+2x^4+x^5][1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^7]$$
This means we can replace two $6$-sided dice with, for example, a die with faces of $2,3,3,4,4,5$ and a die with faces of $0,2,3,4,5,7$, and the sum from rolling these two dice will have the same probability distribution as rolling two standard $6$-sided dice. We can extend this process to the generating functions for more $6$-sided dice and create some wacky dice that still have the same probability distribution.

Comment: So, it is possible to use a 60 face die, just that the values would not be 1 to 60 on the faces? then I cold lets say, have a table on hand that has an index of original face numbers that give us the correct result from the probabilities of the equivalent Dn die?

Comment: This would not work as there are only $51$ distinct sums you can get from $10$ $6$-sided die. You might think that a $51$-sided dice (if one were to exist) numbered from $10$ to $60$ would be the same as rolling 10 $6$-sided die, but as shown in my answer, this would also have a different probability distribution generating function.

Comment: I see... then even if we had a hypothetical fair die that is bigger than 120, unless we did an insane thing that accounts for all the possible probabilities of the 10 D6 we wouldn't be able to replace them with a single die? like a 60,466,176-sided die?

Comment: Exactly, we wouldn't be able to replace the 10 D6 with a single standard die. However, we could replace the 10 D6 with a nonstandard (but fair) D$6^{10}$ die. For example in a simpler case, we could replace a pair of D6 with a D36 die that had faces $2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,12$

Answer (score 3):

A simple argument is you can roll a $1$ using one $60$ sided die but you cannot using ten $6$ sided dice.

Comment: wow that's right

Answer (score 1):

When you roll a 60-face die, you are in effect rolling ten six-face dice but counting only one at a time, which is very different from counting the entire combination of ten independent six-face dice.

You can approximate a fair 60-face die with a red six-face die, a blue one and several white ones, call the number of white dice $n$. Interpret a roll as follows:

- Count the actual outcome of the red die.
- Count the blue die as 1 if its outcome is odd, 2 if even.
- Sum the white dice and divide by 5; count the remainder. You may add 1 to each remainder, or exchange a remainder of 0 for 5, if you want this number to range from 1 to 5 instead of 0 to 4.

You then have 60 ordered triples whose probabilities are nearly equal for reasonable values of $n$. The only deviation is associated with the remainder from the white-dice sum divided by $5$ being congruent with $n\bmod 5$. In that case the probability is increased by a factor of $(6^n+4)/(6^n-1)$ compared with the other remainders (which all come out equal). This corresponds to an excess of just over 2% with $n=3$ and less than 0.4% with $n=4$. Each increment of $n$ by $1$ reduces the deviation by a factor of six.

Comment: Interesting, but this is the opposite case, replacing a a D60 with some D6's

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto other answers…

Rolling ten six-sided dice, the most likely sum you are to get is $\frac{1+6}{2}*10=35.$ Then, getting a sum of $34$ is slightly less likely than getting a sum of $35$. Etc… all the way down to getting a sum of $10$, which has probability just $\frac{1}{6^{10}}.$

But with a $60-$ sided die, the probability of getting a $10$ is just $\frac{1}{60}.$